# If translated into Javascript, can I run this program in Google Sheets?

Tags: python, excel, google-sheets, translate

Google Sheets uses Javascript for custom programming. I'm wondering if [this program I've written in Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ornfW.png) would be able to be run in Google Sheets if translated into Javascript. Thank you!

Comment: Please don't post code as image

Comment: Like @cybernetic.nomad said, don't post code as an image. You can embed it directly into your question so we can read it.

My question for you is: Have you tried it? If so, where did you run into problems?

Comment: From a look at the code, yes that seems possible.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in Apps Script. Check the reference and how to use Spreadsheets methods in Apps Script.

Here you have some useful links:

[Apps Script Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)

[SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)

[Class: Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet)

[Class: Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)